# Multiple config file postfix

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, mail-server

Our mail server was configured using this tutorial: [Pixelinx - Creating a Mail Server on Ubuntu (Postfix, Courier, SSL/TLS, SpamAssassin, ClamAV, Amavis)](http://www.pixelinx.com/2010/10/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-and-amavis/)

Now it can receive/send email using his addresses me@foo.com, me2@foo.com, ...

I would like to know if it is possible to config the mail server to receive/send mails with a second domain name (me@bar.com, me2@bar.com , ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best choice - [Virtual domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html)

More [stuff](http://netwinsite.com/surgemail/help/domains.htm) to read.

Even more [stuff](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD3b6JOdf7E) to watch.

**UPDATE** as requested.

Mail server can handle e-mail traffic for multiple domains. This technology is called "Virtual domains". Simply saying, mail server (Postfix) can be configured to accept e-mails for different destination domains. There is setting in the configuration which tells e-mails for which destination mail server should accept.

Simplest setup assumes that mail server for domain example.com would accept e-mails only for example.com. We can expand it to accept e-mails for example1.com, example2.com and super-example500.com.

How server is handling these e-mails for different destinations - will it deliver them to local MDA or relay it to another server - another question.

And there are different ways of setting it up depending on your software. Google for "E-mail virtual domains" and this will bring you a lot of helpful stuff.

Additionally I will say - you will have to tweak not just mail software configuration, but DNS records. [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) defines which servers handle e-mails for particular domain.

Comment: While "virtual domains" does seem to be the answer to the question, and especially the first link seems unlikely to become invalid in the near future, it would be greatly beneficial if you can summarize the key points from the linked pages in your answer, so that if the links ever do become invalid the answer will still be useful.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, thank you for correcting me on this point. I put more data. Now it is more explained.